# Format a string as a date

Tags: c++, string, date

I have a `string date` and I need to format it as a date (dd.mm.yyyy).How can I do that?Are there some functions that can simplify formatting?

LE:"Write a c++ program which helps you to manage tasks...A task has a unique format,id,description,date(string having the format "dd.MM.yyyy", eg 10.07.2013)."

Comment: What is a *"`string date`"*? Something like "10th of July 2013"?

Comment: And what does it contain?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time

Comment: @jrok date is a string which contains a date in the format "dd.mm.yyyy".I can't use other data types,I have to format the string to look like a date.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, use [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) first, then use `std::put_time` to output it how you want.

Comment: @Matt: If the string contains the date in the format `dd.mm.yyyy`, why do you even need to format it? That makes no sense at all! You should provide a minimal example of your problem, as your question and comments are currently misleading.

Comment: @Zeta, Because the OP realizes that `dd.mm.yyyy` is a horrible format, but can't control how they get it, and wants it in `yyyy-mm-dd`? That might be slightly optimistic.

Comment: @chris: Keep in mind that good old `g++` [doesn't support `put_time` yet](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54354). :(. Concering the date-thingy: I just realized that OP maybe hasn't specified the target format yet.

Comment: @Zeta, Yeah, as I found out recently enough :/ At least the language part is pretty much done :) There is `strftime` as well, which it uses and works well enough for formats that weren't added later.

Comment: Please do not confuse parsing with formatting ... Probably editing the question would be helpful too. If you find yourself in confusion or lack of words to properly describe the problem it is always a good idea to present an example of input and output. I.e. "I have a `string date = "01.01.1970"`. I want to have a `c++` date object, or I want to have "01-01-1970"."

Comment: Try [boost.date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time.html) in case you want to handle more in future.

Answer (score 1):

try this  , this give you the system time in a char[32]

```
time_t curtime;
struct tm *loctime;
char date_str[32];

curtime = time (NULL);

/* Convert it to local time representation. */
loctime = localtime (&curtime);
strftime (date_str, 32, "%d.%m.%Y", loctime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific of the C++ that you are using. If its C++/CLI, then you can use

```
DateTime::Parse
```

If its not C++/CLI and you know the exact format of the string you can use

```
sscanf(....)
```

and extract individual items to assign to time struct.

Comment: If it's C++/CLI, it should be tagged as such and not have a C++ tag.

Answer (score 0):

`C++` standard library does not provide time data type  but you can do by including  `ctime` in header file.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
    cout << (now->tm_year + 1900) << '-' 
         << (now->tm_mon + 1) << '-'
         <<  now->tm_mday
         << endl;
}
```

Comment: "Class template std::chrono::time_point represents a point in time." I'd say that qualifies.